# Send logs from docker container to Windows host

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, containers

I've seen other posts with similar questions but I can't find a solution for my case scenario. I hope someone can help.

Here is the thing: I have a python script that listens for UDP traffic and stores the messages in a log file. I've put this script in a docker image so I can run it in a container.

I need to map the generated logs (python script logs) **FROM** inside the container **TO** a folder outside the container, on the host machine (***Windows*** host).
If I use docker-compose everything works fine!! but I can't find the way to make it work using a "*docker run ...*" command.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  '20001':
    image: udplistener
    container_name: '20001'
  ports:
    - 20001:20001/udp
  environment:
    - UDP_PORT=20001
    - BUFFER_SIZE=1024
  volumes:
    - ./UDPLogs/20001:/usr/src/app/logs
```

And here is the corresponding docker run command:

```
docker run -d --name 20001 -e UDP_PORT=20001 -e BUFFER_SIZE=1024 -v "/C/Users/kgonzale/Desktop/UDPLogs/20001":/usr/src/app/logs -p 20001:20001 udplistener
```

I think the problem may be related to the way I'm creating the volumes, I know is different (docker-compose -> Relative path) (docker command -> Absolute path) but I can't find the way to use relative paths when using the docker run command..

**To summarize:** the python script is creating logs Inside the container, I want to map those logs Outside the container. I can see the logs in the host machine if I use "***docker-compose up -d***" but I need the "***docker run ...***" corresponding command.

- Container: python:3.7-alpine
- Host: Windows 10

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yo should remove the first slash from absolute path. Use `C:/Users/kgonzale/Desktop/UDPLogs/20001` that is absolute path for windows. You were using linux path scheme

Comment: Thanks @SaGaR for responding!, Unfortunately, if I remove that slash the UDPLogs/20001 folders are not created, thus no logs are mapped out the container.

I mean, those folders are meant to be created automatically when I start the container

Comment: You should try using path for wsl as since wsl is used as backend for docker maybe that'll help. I mean something like   `/mnt/c/users/<rest-of-your-path>`

Comment: I recommend using a named volume on Windows or as @SaGaR said use a WSL path